# Split list of lists into lists knowing index of end

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm having troubles after many tries and research on internet for spliting a list of list into separated lists.

I have the following [File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE5Mq.png) containing load cases separated by begin and end sequences. This file could have 4 or n load cases with 10 or n stations so the code should operate the same whatever their number. My goal is to create a numpy array for each load case so in this example 4 arrays.

I first read the file and detected begin and end sequences, added a keyword 'fin' to know the separation of load cases.

```
def read(filename): 
with open(filename,'r') as f : 
    copy = False
    L=[]
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == "BEGIN":
            copy = True
            continue
            
        elif line.strip() == "END":
            copy = False
            L.append(['fin'])
            
            continue
        
        
        elif copy :
            # print([float(i) for i in line.split()])
            L.append(line.split())
   
        
return(L)
```

Here begins my problem, I can't find a way to separate this big list of list L to get 4 lists or arrays of my load cases. I tried something by getting the index of the "fin" keywords but I can only print the load cases not put them in separated variables as Python for loop doesn't allow to dynamically create new variables in each iteration.

```
index = [i for i, value in enumerate(L) if value == ['fin']]
    print(index)
    print(L[0:index[0]])
    for i in range(len(index)-1):
        print(np.array(L[index[i]+1:index[i+1]]))
```

Hope this was clear, thanks !

```
$-Station---$-coord(m)--$Fx---------$Fy---------$Fz---------$Mx---------$My---------$Mz---------$
BEGIN
         1.0         1.0        10.0        20.0        30.0         0.0       210.0      -140.0
         1.0         2.0        20.0        40.0        60.0         0.0       390.0      -260.0
         1.0         3.0        30.0        60.0        90.0         0.0       540.0      -360.0
         1.0         4.0        40.0        80.0       120.0       180.0       660.0      -500.0
         1.0         5.0        50.0       100.0       150.0       540.0       750.0      -680.0
         1.0         6.0        60.0       120.0       180.0       540.0       810.0      -720.0
         1.0         7.0        70.0       140.0       210.0       540.0       840.0      -740.0
         1.0         8.0        30.0        60.0        90.0         0.0       -90.0        60.0
         1.0         9.0        20.0        40.0        60.0         0.0       -90.0        60.0
         1.0        10.0        10.0        20.0        30.0         0.0       -60.0        40.0
END
$-Station---$-coord(m)--$Fx---------$Fy---------$Fz---------$Mx---------$My---------$Mz---------$
BEGIN
         1.0         1.0        20.0        20.0        30.0         0.0       210.0      -140.0
         1.0         2.0        30.0        40.0        60.0         0.0       390.0      -260.0
         1.0         3.0        40.0        60.0        90.0         0.0       540.0      -360.0
         1.0         4.0        50.0        80.0       120.0       180.0       660.0      -500.0
         1.0         5.0        60.0       100.0       150.0       540.0       750.0      -680.0
         1.0         6.0        70.0       120.0       180.0       540.0       810.0      -720.0
         1.0         7.0        80.0       140.0       210.0       540.0       840.0      -740.0
         1.0         8.0        30.0        60.0        90.0         0.0       -90.0        60.0
         1.0         9.0        20.0        40.0        60.0         0.0       -90.0        60.0
         1.0        10.0        10.0        20.0        30.0         0.0       -60.0        40.0
END
$-Station---$-coord(m)--$Fx---------$Fy---------$Fz---------$Mx---------$My---------$Mz---------$
BEGIN
         1.0         1.0        30.0        20.0        30.0         0.0       210.0      -140.0
         1.0         2.0        40.0        40.0        60.0         0.0       390.0      -260.0
         1.0         3.0        50.0        60.0        90.0         0.0       540.0      -360.0
         1.0         4.0        60.0        80.0       120.0       180.0       660.0      -500.0
         1.0         5.0        70.0       100.0       150.0       540.0       750.0      -680.0
         1.0         6.0        80.0       120.0       180.0       540.0       810.0      -720.0
         1.0         7.0        90.0       140.0       210.0       540.0       840.0      -740.0
         1.0         8.0        30.0        60.0        90.0         0.0       -90.0        60.0
         1.0         9.0        20.0        40.0        60.0         0.0       -90.0        60.0
         1.0        10.0        10.0        20.0        30.0         0.0       -60.0        40.0
END
$-Station---$-coord(m)--$Fx---------$Fy---------$Fz---------$Mx---------$My---------$Mz---------$
BEGIN
         1.0         1.0        40.0        20.0        30.0         0.0       210.0      -140.0
         1.0         2.0        50.0        40.0        60.0         0.0       390.0      -260.0
         1.0         3.0        60.0        60.0        90.0         0.0       540.0      -360.0
         1.0         4.0        70.0        80.0       120.0       180.0       660.0      -500.0
         1.0         5.0        80.0       100.0       150.0       540.0       750.0      -680.0
         1.0         6.0        90.0       120.0       180.0       540.0       810.0      -720.0
         1.0         7.0       100.0       140.0       210.0       540.0       840.0      -740.0
         1.0         8.0        30.0        60.0        90.0         0.0       -90.0        60.0
         1.0         9.0        20.0        40.0        60.0         0.0       -90.0        60.0
         1.0        10.0        10.0        20.0        30.0         0.0       -60.0        40.0
END
```

Comment: Please paste the contents here

Comment: You mean the code ?

Comment: @Damelko he meant the data in the file

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "4 or n load cases with 10 or n stations".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then perhaps a list of lists will help. For example:-

I create a file that looks like this:-

BEGIN
A
B
C
END
foo
BEGIN
X
Y
Z
END
foo

...then...

```
L = []

with open('/Users/andy/begin.txt') as infile:
    IL = None
    for line in infile:
        ls = line.rstrip('\n')
        if ls == 'BEGIN':
            IL = []
        elif ls == 'END':
            L.append(IL)
            IL = None
        elif IL is not None:
            IL.append(ls)

print(L)
```

...will give this result...

[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z']]

This code may not be robust as it assumes that END always succeeds an occurrence of BEGIN

Comment: Thanks, but I will have the same problem later on when I want to separate this list of lists into differents lists or arrays... The expected results is L1 = [A,B,C] and L2 = [X,Y,Z] nut I can't do this by hand if there are 100 load cases.

Comment: But with this code and your example, L1 is equivalent to L[0]. I'm not sure if I understand your problem

Comment: Yes exactly I can acces my load cases in L[i] with your code. But I can't find a way to put all these L[i] in other variables as I really need to manipulate them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator and remove "fin" and the `copy` variable.

In the generator function below, note the `yield` statement, which "yields" load cases one by one, without exiting the function. That's what makes this function a generator.

```
def read_loadcases(filename):
    loadcase = []
    # NOTE: lines before first BEGIN will be collected but thrown away
    with open(filename,'r') as f :
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == "BEGIN":
                loadcase = []
                continue
            if line.strip() == "END":
                yield loadcase
                continue
            loadcase.append(line.split())
```

The generator function above relies on BEGIN and END being reliably placed in the file, enclosing each load case. No "fin" marker is necessary in the output because the generator spits out load cases one at a time.

You can use the above generator as follows:

```
for loadcase in read_loadcases(filename):
    do_something_with(loadcase)
```

For example:

```
for loadcase in read_loadcases(filename):
    print(len(loadcase))
```

or:

```
for lc in read_loadcases(filename):
    loadcase = np.array(lc)
    # process loadcase using numpy facilities
```

This will work no matter how many load cases are in the original file. Only the current loadcase is ever in memory.

If you want to put the load cases in separate named variables (perhaps, for example, the first 4 load cases are special), you could do something like the following:

```
loadcase_iterator = read_loadcases(filename)
loadcase1 = loadcase_iterator.__next__()
loadcase2 = loadcase_iterator.__next__()
loadcase3 = loadcase_iterator.__next__()
loadcase4 = loadcase_iterator.__next__()
```

If you need the last index of each loadcase, you can use `len(loadcase3) - 1` for example.

The rest of the load cases can be processed using:

```
for loadcase in loadcase_iterator:
    do_something_with(loadcase)
```

which will start with the next loadcase after `loadcase4`.

If you're going to be working with large files, learning about generators and iterators would repay you many times over.

[This article](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) walks through an example that reads a large file and may be helpful.

David Beazley's [Generator Tricks for System Programmers](https://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/%7Ejzhu/csc326/readings/Generators.pdf) is a classic tutorial for anyone processing large files. The first few pages of the tutorial should get you started with generators and iterators.